# check fstab order

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to write a python script to check if "parent" mount point 
exists before "child" mount point , for example
`/mnt` should be before `/mnt/mount1`

this is what I have wrote so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python

for line in open("/etc/fstab", "r"): 
  line = line.strip() 
  if line == "":
     continue

  lintyp = linetype(line)  
  if lintyp >= type:
     type = lintyp
```

either with python or even bash

Answer (score 0):

Youn can use `fstab` module, I used `StringIO.StringIO` to replace `open('/etc/fstab', 'r')`:

```
import StringIO
from fstab import Fstab

s = content = """\
# this is a comment, followed by an empty line
# the next line is a syntax error
yo!
#UUID="2b0ab63e-fd1b-4d7a-b021-3827b4aa4c8b" /media/hda3 ext3 defaults 0 2
/dev/hda2 /boot ext3 defaults 0 2
/dev/hda1 / ext3 defaults,errors=remount-ro 0 1
"""

fstab = Fstab()
#fstab.read(open('/etc/fstab', 'r'))
fstab.read(StringIO.StringIO(content))

output = []
_fs = []
for line in fstab.lines:
    if line.has_filesystem():
        _fs.append(line.raw)
    else:
        output.append(line.raw)

_fs = sorted(_fs)
output.extend(_fs)


output = '\n'.join(line for line in output)
print output
#You have just to write to '/etc/fstab'
```

Comment: Fstab module doesn't exists on my systems   ,can you please provide other solutions /example?

Comment: @Max_il In your example you opened a local file.Please edit your code and describe what you can do to get that file.